# A recurrence relation problem involving intersecting circles?

Tags: recurrence-relations

Respected Sir,
Please give a complete information about the following one:

Find a recurrence relation for the number of regions created by 'n' mutually intersecting circles on a piece of paper (no three circles have a common intersecting point).

if you could be a clear a possible with your answer that would be awesome... thanks.

Comment: And respected Madams? Anyway, do you mean the *maximum* number of regions? I'm not sure if that can be put into a simple recurrence.

Answer (score 4):

Google search for [recurrence regions circles](http://www.google.com/#&q=recurrence+regions+circles) led me to [this document](http://www.math.ust.hk/~mabfchen/Math232/Recurrence-Relation-Generating-Function.pdf).

Example 1.1 gives a derivation of formulas $a_n=a_{n-1}+2(n-1)$ and $a_n=n^2-n+2$. (If I understood your question correctly, it is identical to this example.)

BTW the google search provided also [this answer](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080428234221AAlvwrT), which seems to be incorrect.

Answer (score -2):

I found the answer to be a sub n = a sub n minus 1 + n. it works for the first 5 initial conditions (by drawing out the circles and by inspection). i agree that the google answer is wrong, because then a sub 3 could not equal 6 (even though it does) because 2 cubed is 8, not 6.

Comment: what is a sub n? please try to be a little bit more clear

Comment: I am not sure how to explain what a sub n is. a sub n is what were trying to solve for, in this case, a sub n = the number of regions created by n mutually intersecting circles on a piece of paper.